# Quickblox friendlist in javascript?

Tags: quickblox

In the documentation, there are examples of how to do this in android or ios: http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Contact_list

however I am not certain how to do this with the javascript API, how might one do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Javascript Roster documentation

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Code_snippets_.28Roster.29